# ArrrayAdapter requires resourceID to be a text view

Tags: android, arrays, textview, resource-id

The goal of this project of mine is to update a spinner dynamically with user input. Unfortunately I'm losing this battle. Logcat keeps throwing the resource ID error at me, HOWEVER, I don't understand why it's only thrown on button press, wouldn't it be thrown after onCreate, if that's where the problem is?

Eclipse (via ctrl + space) tells me the to specify the Resource ID of the layout CONTAINING the TextView. Which I also don't even understand why I would need a textview, if I'm just handling an array and a spinner. AndroidDevelopment site also says the same. I'm just confused.So, my question is, what does this error mean, and what am I doing wrong?

I BELIEVE this is the line in question:

```
list = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.settings,items);
```

This is the .java

```
    package com.example.thepicker;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Settings extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


    EditText getit;
    ImageButton giveit;
    Spinner thelist;
    ArrayList<String> items;
    ArrayAdapter<String> list;
    String transit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        items = new ArrayList<String>();
        list = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.settings,items);
        getit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.getit);
        giveit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.giveit);
        thelist = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.thelist);


        thelist.setAdapter(list);
        giveit.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String transit = getit.getText().toString();
        items.add(transit);
        list.insert(transit, 0);
        list.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This is the logcat

```
03-11 01:39:25.682: E/Trace(1722): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-11 01:39:26.452: D/libEGL(1722): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
03-11 01:39:26.532: D/(1722): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x556a6180, tid 1722
03-11 01:39:26.602: D/libEGL(1722): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
03-11 01:39:26.623: D/libEGL(1722): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
03-11 01:39:26.761: W/EGL_emulation(1722): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-11 01:39:26.772: D/OpenGLRenderer(1722): Enabling debug mode 0
03-11 01:39:30.483: W/EGL_emulation(1722): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-11 01:39:36.412: E/ArrayAdapter(1722): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
03-11 01:39:36.412: D/AndroidRuntime(1722): Shutting down VM
03-11 01:39:36.423: W/dalvikvm(1722): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2bd39930)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:193)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:439)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:645)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:425)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
03-11 01:39:36.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     ... 35 more
03-11 01:39:36.682: D/dalvikvm(1722): GC_CONCURRENT freed 188K, 4% free 6367K/6596K, paused 90ms+4ms, total 255ms
03-11 01:39:40.702: I/Process(1722): Sending signal. PID: 1722 SIG: 9
03-11 01:39:41.192: E/Trace(1747): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-11 01:39:41.992: D/libEGL(1747): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
03-11 01:39:42.092: D/(1747): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x556a6180, tid 1747
03-11 01:39:42.376: D/libEGL(1747): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
03-11 01:39:42.394: D/libEGL(1747): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
03-11 01:39:42.674: W/EGL_emulation(1747): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-11 01:39:43.465: D/OpenGLRenderer(1747): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: Have you tried to clean your project?

Comment: @codeMagic yes, I have. :) Unfortunately no effect. I have all the pieces, I'm just putting them together wrong I'm sure. I have the tendency to overlook even the most obvious things.

Comment: Why are you changing your 'Layout' in the `onClick()`? I don't think your old views will exist once you call `setContentView()` again

Comment: as far as I remember, calling `setContentView` more than once should be avoided since it causes unexpected behaviour

Comment: @codeMagic I accidentally posted old code that I was using for debugging purposes (commenting out lines of code for result). Updated with an edit. Sorry.

Comment: @m1shk4 It was an accident, that isn't in the code. See above comment. :/ Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Try changing `R.layout.settings` to `android.R.id.text1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the problem to be in the line:

```
list = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.settings,items);
```

please try to replace `R.layout.settings` with `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`

second parameter is a resource identifier, that should point to the `TextView` with `id="@android/text1"`(that is what Android expects)

`android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` corresponds to predefined `TextView` layout, that is located in the SDK folder(try to look into the folder, where SDK is installed: `<SDK_FOLDER>/platforms/<select_any_platform_by_api_level>/data/res/layout/simple_spinner_item.xml`, there are some pretty nice predefined layouts, that should help you understand the logic)

Comment: Okay so it works. Awesome. How come I have to use that? What dictates that and where can I find it? Is this tribal knowledge for you? :S I just would NEVER have guessed that that was the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Leaves the question: “Where is this documented”?

Comment: unfortunately, it seems to be kinda obvious :) using ID pointing to a `TextView` is dictated by the exception message

Answer (score 2):

Since ArrayAdapter requires a TextView, as the exception says, you have two options:

1. Change `R.layout.settings` to `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`.
2. Create your own Adapter subclass which inflates your custom layout.

Comment: very much the answer to my problems. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Leaves the question: “Where is this documented”? — Just here is Stackoverflow?

Comment: @Martin "By default this class expects that the provided resource id references a single TextView." http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Comment: @Martin It looks like there is a third solution: use a different constructor for `ArrayAdapter`.